# Python Twisted: Changing directories for each client independently

Tags: python, client-server, twisted

I'm new to Python Twisted, and I decided to create this as part of my learning process:

I created a TCP client and server using Python Twisted. The client can send commands to the server to list directory, change directory, and view file. All of these work the way I want them to, but when I connect multiple clients to the server, and I change directories in one of them, it changes directories on the other clients too! Is there a way to make these independent?

Server Code

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

import os

class BrowserServer(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        command = data.split()

        message = ""

        if command[0] == "c":
            try:
                if os.path.isdir(command[1]):
                    os.chdir(command[1])
                    message = "Okay"
                else:
                    message = "Bad path"
            except IndexError:
                message = "Usage: c <path>"
        elif command[0] == "l":
            for i in os.listdir("."):
                message += "\n" + i
        elif command[0] == "g":
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(command[1]):
                    f = open(command[1])
                    message = f.read()
            except IndexError:
                message = "Usage: g <file>"
            except IOError:
                message = "File doesn't exist"
        else:
            message = "Bad command"

        self.transport.write(message)

class BrowserFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return BrowserServer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reactor.listenTCP(8123, BrowserFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Client Code

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class BrowserClient(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connected"
        self.userInput()

    def dataReceived(self, line):
        print line
        self.userInput()

    def userInput(self):
        command = raw_input(">")
        if command == "q":
            print "Bye"
            self.transport.loseConnection()
        else:
            self.sendLine(command)

class BrowserFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = BrowserClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection failed: ", reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection lost: ", reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8123, BrowserFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot, even using thread `chdir` will affect all threads in process (iirc), keep the directory reference and call `listdir` and `open` with full path